# How do I open a cmd

Tags: cmd

I have been looking for a way to open a cmd on my Chromebook. I have tried downloading file converters that aren't blocked. That didn't work. Any one know how to open a cmd on Chromebook. Also by the way this is my school computer.

Comment: Shortcut: Ctrl+Alt+T ??

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant "shell".

Press CTRL – ALT – T and you will have a browser-based shell known as Crosh.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. CMD is a Windows NT and OS/2 command prompt (plus there is a NT4 and Win2000 port to Win9x). It doesn't work on other operating systems. You can't run Windows programs on toy OSs like Chrome.